# "Prop up the table"

Tags: phrases, expressions, british-english, sports, journalism

> Under Moyes, United have fewer home points (21) than Norwich City and Hull City, with their count of 18 goals the same as Fulham and Cardiff City, who **prop up the table**. ([source](https://www.theguardian.com/football/blog/2014/mar/26/david-moyes-manchester-united-dead-man-walking))

The phrase "prop up the table" strikes me as odd, and it doesn't appear to be a set phrase as I can't find many other attestations. Wiktionary has a definition "To be at the bottom of (a league)" under *prop up*; this definition, however, does not seem to appear anywhere else. "Table" here, I assume, refers to a sports league's ranking or chart. Is this phrase "prop up the table" something particular to UK sports writing?

Comment: I wonder if it isn't a poker idiom.

Comment: The quoted definition, which seems correctly interpreted in the question, references a “football” game—soccer in the States.